# Why is $xyzx^{-1}y^{-1}z^{-1}$ a commutator?

Tags: group-theory

Exercise 1.6.41(a) of Bourbaki's Algebra goes like this:

---

Let $x,y$ be two elements of a group $G$. For there to exist $a,b$ in $G$ such that $bay=xab$, it is necessary and sufficient that $xy^{-1}$ be a commutator.

---

The necessity part is nothing else than the statement that for arbitrary elements $x,a,b\in G$, $bayb^{-1}a^{-1}y^{-1}$ is a commutator. But this is not obvious to me at all. I have the feeling I am missing something very simple. Can someone help?

Comment: It is the commutator of $ba$ with $ya$.

Comment: Or rather, under Bourbaki's convention, of $a^{-1}b^{-1}$ with $a^{-1}y^{-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
x^{-1}y^{-1}z^{-1}xyz &= y(y^{-1}x^{-1}y^{-1}z^{-1}xyzy)y^{-1}\\
&= y\left((xy)^{-1}(zy)^{-1}(xy)(zy)\right)y^{-1}\\
&= y[xy,zy]y^{-1}\\
&= [xy,zy]^{y^{-1}}\\
&= \left[(xy)^{y^{-1}},(zy)^{y^{-1}}\right]\\
&= \left[yx,yz\right]
\end{align*}$$
for all $x,y,z\in G$.